# JS (no lookback) regex for replacing :bound SQL vars without replacing 'colons:in:literals' ...?

Tags: javascript, mysql, regex

Messing around with node-mysql, I wrote some code that lets me use PDO-style :bound values (plus ::bound field names), and rewrites the query with ? and ?? respectively where they are found, and builds a linear array of the values when I execute the statement. I did this because when I look at a SQL statement with a ton of ? ?? all over it and have to count the number of params in my execution, it makes my eyes bleed. I want to just assign a standard object at execution time.

The trouble is, after writing this (it works) I realized my regex for finding those colons in the statement had one *tiny* little problem, namely, it looks like this:

```
/.?:(\w+)/g
```

It picks up the first colon if needed and we take it from there. The problem is, it also picks up colons in literals within the query. So if for some reason you wanted a non-bound string as part of your insert/update, it would be replaced by this engine.

Is there any standard regex for picking up every global instance of the word ":param{#}" in the following statement, without picking up the word "Hello:world", in JS, without lookbacks?

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES(:param1, :param2, 'Hello:world', :param3);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're often much better off writing a parser than using regular expressions. It's much more flexible, gives you better error reporting and allows you to handle current & future edge cases much more easily.

The string parsing deals with MySQL string literals syntax & escape sequences described [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-literals.html) and just skips over them.

I'm not dealing with valid/invalid binding boundaries, but you could add that if you wanted. You could also remove error reporting such as underterminated string literals and just be forgiving.

The `lookahead === ':' && peek() !== '='` condition is to ignore the `:=` MySQL operator.

```js
const parseBindings = (() => {
    const bindingCharRx = /\w/;

    return function(sql) {
        const bindings = [];
        let i = 0,
            lookahead = sql[i];

        while (lookahead) {
            if (isStringDelim(lookahead)) parseString();
            else if (lookahead === ':' && peek() !== '=') parseBinding();
            else consume();
        }

        return bindings;

        function parseString() {
            const start = i,
                delim = lookahead;
            consume();
            while (lookahead) {
                if (lookahead === '\\') {
                    consume();
                    consume();
                    continue;
                }

                if (lookahead === delim) {
                    consume();
                    if (lookahead !== delim) return;
                }

                consume();
            }

            throw new Error(`Underterminated string literal starting at index ${start}.`);
        }

        function isStringDelim(char) {
            return char === "'" || char === '"';
        }

        function parseBinding() {
            const start = i;
            consume();

            while (lookahead && bindingCharRx.test(lookahead)) consume();

            const name = sql.slice(start + 1, i);

            if (!name.length) {
                throw new Error(`Invalid binding starting at index ${start}.`);
            }

            bindings.push({
                start,
                end: i,
                name: name
            });
        }

        function consume() {
            lookahead = sql[++i]
        }

        function peek() {
            return sql[i + 1]
        }

    }
})();

function replaceNamedBindings(values, sql) {
    const bindings = parseBindings(sql);
    const bindingNames = new Set(bindings.map(b => b.name));
    const unknownBinding = Object.keys(values).find(k => !bindingNames.has(k));

    if (unknownBinding) throw new Error(`Couldn't find a binding named '${unknownBinding}'.`);

    let lastIndex = 0,
        newSql = '';

    for (const binding of bindings) {
        if (binding.name in values) {
            newSql += sql.slice(lastIndex, binding.start) + values[binding.name];
            lastIndex = binding.end;
        }
    }

    newSql += sql.slice(lastIndex);

    return newSql;
}

const sql = `INSERT INTO test VALUES(:param1, :param2, 'Hello:world', :param3);`;


console.log(replaceNamedBindings({
    param1: '(param1 value)',
    param2: '(param2 value)',
    param3: '(param3 value)'
}, sql));
console.log(parseBindings(sql));

console.log(parseBindings(`:pickup1 ":dontpickup1" ':dontpickup2' := """:dontpickup3" ''':dontpickup4' "\\":dontpickup5" :pickup2`));

//Will throw exception b/c :world is not a binding
console.log(replaceNamedBindings({
    world: '(world value)'
}, sql));
```

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer! Proper error handling and all. Excellent!

Comment: @joshstrike No problem! I didin't know exactly what you needed, but you should be able to extend this answer. If you need the adjust anything let me know. Also like I said I didin't handle cases like `:param1#O$(#` as invalid, b/c many operators are non `\w`, but valid. You'd have to enumerate them all to make it bullet-proof, such as `+`, `*`, etc. so that `:param1+:param2` is valid, but `:param1#:param2` is not. You could also force a space between params to make things simpler though.

Comment: Good point. I don't think I've ever named a parameter something non \w but in my case it would be apparent from the SQL error what the issue was. My usage of this is to set up server-side and also emulated prepared statements with mysqljs, so I'm converting all bound :params to ? (and ::fields to ??, where possible under emulation) and returning a statement object with an ordered list of bound names that can be executed on later, async. PDO-style mysqljs. For the moment this is great, I got it working in Typescript with a peek() for the extra ::field colon. I'll post a GH link and credit you!

Comment: I've included your parser in the first commit for this project. I'd love to get your feedback if node-mysql is your thing! https://github.com/joshstrike/StrikeDB

Comment: I never used node-mysql, but this looks like an interesting project ;) Just looked at some docs and they seem to support extensions for [custom format](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql) methods which you may want to leverage using your own bindings parser. I also checked quickly and I wouldn't mix emulation in the standard API. Perhaps you could consider a decorator if possible or a distinct class? Not so sure what's the role of emulation? Is it for testing? If it is then perhaps you should introduce a `Connection` abstraction like `RealConnection` and `EmulatedConnection`.

Comment: Hah! I seem to have missed that custom formatting option. But I don't know if it makes sense to leverage it since ? formatting is still needed for server-side prepared statements. node-mysql doesn't support server-side prepare or execute at all, it only emulates them. It also escapes values in JS, which I'm not 100% comfortable with. While one purpose of this code is to build true prepares if desired, their emulation has the benefit of being able to bind table and field names if you don't mind local escapes. I think you're right about splitting up the classes... good call ;) Thank you again!